# Python3 question about dictionaries from a newcomer to the language

Tags: python, dictionary

So I'm trying to get data from the League of Legends database using their API. I have almost no background in python but the language i know wont help at all (matlab).

So far i've managed to get a huge THING that has the data from a game, ids of players, scores... useful bits. But i dont know how to read specific bits about it. If i print the THING (please tell me how this is called i have no idea, looks like lists inside lists maybe):

```
{'gameId': 4630243428, 'platformId': 'EUW1', 'gameCreation': 1590736089890, 'gameDuration': 1139, 'queueId': 420, 'mapId': 11, 'seasonId': 13, 'gameVersion': '10.11.322.2991', 'gameMode': 'CLASSIC',
'gameType': 'MATCHED_GAME', 'teams': [{'teamId': 100, 'win': 'Win', 'firstBlood': False, 'firstTower': True, 'firstInhibitor': False, 'firstBaron': False, 'firstDragon': True, 'firstRiftHerald': True, 'towerKills': 3, 'inhibitorKills': 0, 'baronKills': 0, 'dragonKills': 3, 'vilemawKills': 0, 'riftHeraldKills': 1, 'dominionVictoryScore': 0, 'bans': [{'championId': 38, 'pickTurn': 1}, {'championId': 141, 'pickTurn': 2}, {'championId': 350, 'pickTurn': 3}, {'championId': 266, 'pickTurn': 4}, {'championId': 83, 'pickTurn': 5}]}, {'teamId': 200, 'win': 'Fail', 'firstBlood': True, 'firstTower': False, 'firstInhibitor': False, 'firstBaron'
```

This is less than 1/20 of what it contains. Here's a very useful link to their webpage that explains how this THING is structured: https://developer.riotgames.com/apis#match-v4/GET_getMatch

I however wasn't able to do much with it. For example lets say i call this **match_detail**: As specified by the devs, it contains a list called **participantIdentities**, and this contains another list called **player**. Inside that theres a variable of type string titled **summonerName**. Now i try to print that: print(match_detail.participantIdentities.player.summonerName) but an error pops!

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'participantIdentities'

I'm guessing my severe lack of knowledge is the problem and i shouldnt be doing the thing with the dots. How can I get the values contained in the summonername variable?

I just found out by using the type() command that this is a dictionary. I can get the values that are in the first level like strings or lists, but not an element inside one of those lists.
[In short (red is the part of the dictionary that i can't access unless printing everything)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcqWe.png)

---

Okay ill edit this because i found out what was happening. I had a dictionary and inside it, lists, so i need to call elements inside of the list properly:

```
match_detail['participantIdentities'][i]['player']['summonerName']
```

That looks for the key participantIdentities in match_detail. As it is a list, i choose the element i and inside it, proceed as usual with the next keys being player and finally summonerName (which is of type string ofc).

Comment: this is a dictionary. did you look up anything about how to use dictionaries? They are sort of a core feature of the language...

Comment: Once you've got a THING into a variable (lets call it `thing`) you can ask python what it is: `print(type(thing))`. Now you've got something to go on. If your THING is a `<class 'str'>` it means you haven't decoded it yet. I bet its JSON, so `import json` and then `thing2 = json.loads(thing)` docodes it. Now its a `<class dict>` and you can read up on using those.

Comment: @tdelaney nah, they are gettin `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'participantIdentities'`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - OP says THING, also says _please tell me how this is called i have no idea, looks like lists inside lists maybe_ - I suggested a way discover type to answer that problem. OP is using the object incorrectly and knowing how to discover type seems useful to me.

Comment: @tdelaney Okay guys thank you for the quick responses and forgive the stupid question. The "thing" is a dict and didn't know how to extract data from it properly. Thanks!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Okay guys thank you for the quick responses and forgive the stupid question. The "thing" is a dict and didn't know how to extract data from it properly. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelBay. In general if you're going to post a question and then provide an answer, you answer the question as you would any other, rather than editing the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use box brackets instead:

```
print(match_detail['participantIdentities']['player']['summonerName'])
```

And more generally, to access values of a dictionary in Python (say the dictionary is called `myDictionary`):

```
myDictionary['key']   # outputs value associated with 'key' in myDictionary
```

Comment: print(match_detail['participantIdentities']['player']['summonerName'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str                          Still gives an error

Comment: @MichaelBay that's a different, totally unrelated error. And it's telling you *exactly the problem*, `list` indices must be integers, not strings. There is a list somewhere in there.

Comment: @MichaelBay - decompose the problem. Start with `match_detail['participantIdentities']`. Did it work? What's its type? Now go to the next step `['player']` etc... til you find the problem.